# Using INTEGER in SQL with CSV and Netbeans

Tags: java, sql, csv, netbeans

I'm trying to import a CSV table via Netbeans for my Java application.
However, when I try to import values from a CSV file, I get a file type error. It works if I make all the values VARCHARs, but this is inefficient, especially for the short strings of characters that I use.

Here's the CSV file:

```
GameID,GameName,Developer,Engine,PublishYear,Rating
1,Bioshock Infinite,Irrational Games,Unreal Engine 3,2013,10
2,Hitman: Absolution,IO Interactive,Glacier 2,2012,9
3,Killing Floor,Tripwire Interactive,Unreal Engine 2,2009,7
4,Half-Life 2,Valve,Source,2004,7
5,ESV Skyrim,Bethesda Softworks,Creation Engine,2011,8
6,Batman: Arkham City,Rocksteady Studios,Unreal Engine 3,2011,8
7,Portal 2,Valve,Source,2011,8
8,The Witcher 2,CD Projekt RED,REDengine,2011,9
9,Assassin's Creed 2,Ubisoft,Anvil,2010,8
10,Garry's Mod,Facepunch Studios,Source,2004,6
11,GRID 2,Codemasters,EGO 3.0,2013,7
12,Hotline Miami,Dennaton Games,Game Maker,2012,8
13,Just Cause 2,Avalanche Studios,Avalanche Engine 2.0,2010,7
14,Watch Dogs,Ubisoft,Disrupt,2014,8
15,Deus Ex,Ion Storm,Unreal Engine 1,2000,7
16,Trine 2,Frozenbyte,Proprietary,2011,6
```

And here's the table creation statement:

```
CREATE TABLE tblGames ( 
 GameID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
 GameName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
 Developer VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
 Engine VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
 PublishYear VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 Rating SMALLINT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (GameID) 
);
```

And here's the import statement:

```
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_IMPORT_TABLE ( 
 null, 
 'TBLGAMES', 
 'D:\OneDrive\Documents\Topic 9\CSV\tblGames.csv', 
 ',', null, null, 0 
)
```

And this is a copy of the error I get:

```
Error code 30000, SQL state XIE0R: Import error on line 1 of file D:\OneDrive\Documents\Topic 9\CSV\tblGames.csv: Invalid character string format for type INTEGER. 
Error code 99999, SQL state 22018: Invalid character string format for type INTEGER.
```

Now, as I see it, all the GameID values are integers and the ratings are all SMALLINT, so how could there be an error like this?

Comment: It seems the header row is taken as a data record.

Comment: How would I solve that?

Comment: Did not find a way; why not delete the header row, or so.

Comment: Removing the header worked, thank you. It seems Netbeans requires only the data and no labels